# Question for Twilio whatsapp api phone number

Tags: php, node.js, twilio, whatsapp, twilio-api

I am trying to find **WhatsApp API** service as a tool to send messages to our client.

However, I am confused about **Twilio WhatsApp API** phone number.

1. If I use their service (API), do I need to buy their phone number? Can I use my phone number to send messages to clients?
2. If I buy their phone number, can this number be kept until I terminate the contract? (I'm worried that I always need to change the number)
3. Can this number also be used as a regular phone call or SMS?
4. Can **Twilio** keep **WhatsApp** always online? (I have tried other companies, but they cannot do this. Once **WhatsApp** is closed, it will stop sending messages.)
5. Can **Twilio WhatsApp API** support send to group function?
6. What is a template? (Assuming I need to send an alert based on different sensors, can I change the body part to send it to the user? Or do I need to register another template first)?
   [image-body part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/daJD7.png)
7. Does **Twilio** have email / **WhatsApp** to ask questions?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read about [asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) which covers things like not asking multiple questions in a single question.

Answer (score 0):

If I use their service (api), do I need to buy their phone number? Can I use my phone number to send messages to clients?

**Answer**: Today, you will use need to use a Twilio number you WhatsApp enable. You could always [port](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/categories/203267567-Porting) in your number to Twilio, if it is in a supported country.

If I buy their phone number, can this number be kept until I terminate the contract? (I'm worried that I always need to change the number)

**Answer**: Yes.

Can this number also be used as a regular phone call or SMS?

**Answer**: Yes.

Can Twilio keep whatsapp always online? (I have tried other companies, but they cannot do this. Once whatsapp is closed, it will stop sending messages.)

**Answer**: Twilio WhatsApp is an API, there is no application to keep online.

Can Twilio whatsapp api support send to group function?

**Answer**: No.

What is a template? (Assuming I need to send an alert based on different sensors, can I change the body part to send it to the user? Or do I need to register another template first)? image-body part

**Answer**: Templates are described [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/whatsapp/tutorial/send-whatsapp-notification-messages-templates), the text between the curly brackets can be replaced with customized text.

Does twilio have email / whatsapp to ask questions?

**Answer**: Not sure I understand this question. Twilio Sendgrid does offer an Email API but this is separate/distinct from the WhatsApp API. The Twilio WhatsApp integration allows you to seamlessly use the Twilio Messages resources to send SMS or WhatsApp messages, depending on how you prefix the From/To.

Comment: (Twilio WhatsApp is an API, there is no application to keep online.) 
Even if I use their API and their phone number, there is no guarantee that whatsapp is always online? But can api send messages when whatsapp is offline? Because I want to make sure that once the product has an error or other reasons (24 hours/day), my system can use the api to notify the customer immediately.

Comment: Yes, it also has a Read Receipt, to show the WhatsApp message was read, https://www.twilio.com/blog/new-rich-features-support-deeper-customer-engagement-twilio-api-whatsapp.

Comment: Sorry, I am a little confused.
What I want to ask is, when whatapp is offline, can their API support me to send messages to the client? (Or, when whatapp is offline, will the sending function be disabled?) Because Twilio cannot keep the phone (whatsapp) always online.
If the api supports this feature, then I don’t have to set up the machine to keep whatsapp online, and also ensure that my notification system works 24 hours a day.